# Django : Update object in database using UpdateAPIView

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with the the following `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class RawUser(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
    field1 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

And the following `view.py`. The goal of the `UserUpdate` view is to `create` or `update` a user when I get a PUT request.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import generics
from profiling.api.serializers import RawUserSerializer
from profiling.models import RawUser

class UserUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = RawUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RawUserSerializer

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        raw_user_serializer: RawUserSerializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=False)
        raw_user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        # More logic here 

        raw_user = raw_user_serializer.update(instance, raw_user_serializer.validated_data)
        self.perform_update(raw_user_serializer) 

        return JsonResponse({'user_id':raw_user.id}, status = 201)

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = RawUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RawUserSerializer
```

The issue here is that when I try to PUT a user that exists already, I get the following error on `raw_user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`:

```
Bad Request: /api/profiling/users/1/
{
    "id": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

And when I try to PUT a user that doesn't exist already, I get the following error on `instance = self.get_object()`:

```
Not Found: /api/profiling/users/25/
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

Here is my `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/<str:pk>/', views.UserUpdate.as_view(), name='user-create'),
]
```

What am I doing wrong here ? (I don't mind having my user_id in request's body or in URL path)

--- EDIT : Add serializer code ---

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from profiling.models import ProfileProductScore, RawUser, Profile


class RawUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RawUser
        fields = ["id", "field1", "field2"]
```

Comment: Share the serializer.

Comment: I added serializer in the post

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to implement a custom behaviour (not typical CRUD operations) you have to update your API View logic accordingly.

Here is a example:

#### Update API view

```py
# View
class UserUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = RawUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RawUserSerializer

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Trying to get the user from the database and proceed with None if it is not found.
        try:
            instance = self.get_object()
        except RawUser.DoesNotExist:
            instance = None

        raw_user_serializer: RawUserSerializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=False)
        raw_user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)    

        # More logic here 

        # Call Serializer's save method. Note: no need to call `perform_update`.
        raw_user_serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse({'user_id':raw_user.id}, status = 201)

# Serializer
class RawUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RawUser
        read_only_fields = ["id"] # Put `id` into readonly fields in order to remove it from the list of required fields.
        fields = read_only_fields + ["field1", "field2"]
```

The main idea is to do a database lookup beforehand and then allow Serializer to do the job. Another subtle change is to move `id` field from required fields into `ready_only_fields` in order to address the second problem you experience.

I hope this will help. Let me know if you have any questions.